# Not able to call the webelement method in order to pass the parameter of login detail. Working with PageObject

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

This is my HomePage of Page Object where I created WebElement of UserName method and now want to call it in test case case but it not working.
Showing me the error on element line.

```
public class HomePage {

    WebDriver driver;
    By username = By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/input[1]");
    By password = By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[2]/input[1]");
    By login = By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[3]/td[2]/input[1]");
    
    static WebElement element = null;
    
    //Experiment with webelement
    public static WebElement UserName(WebDriver driver) {
        
        element.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/input[1]"));
        
        return element;
        
    }
    
    public static WebElement Password(WebDriver driver) {
        element.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[2]/input[1]"));
        
        return element;
    }
    
    public static WebElement ClickLogin(WebDriver driver) {
        element.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[3]/td[2]/input[1]"));
        return element;
    }
}
```

These are the code of test class

```
//objLogin = new HomePage();
    HomePage objLogin = new HomePage();

//input the username, password and click login.

    objLogin.UserName(driver).sendKeys("mngr279645");
    objLogin.Password(driver).sendKeys("YzarAzy");
    objLogin.ClickLogin(driver).click();
```

Any help will be appreciated.....

Comment: Please provide your exception or error message, otherwise, nobody knows what is not working.

Comment: Sure, when I execute test class with Junit it simple point me to HomePage class line 21 and 46 which are following.                                         element.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/input[1]"));  and the test case got failed as it's can't process to input userdata.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full formatted stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't understand why would you need **WebDriver driver** as you parameter in every selector when you are no using it and it shouldn't be there.

And second I suggest you study more of a PageObject architecture and using Xpath in general. In your comment above I still cannot see error message being shown.

Comment: Thanks,  Error is something like,    java.lang.NullPointerException     at Pageobjects.HomePage.UerName(HomePage.java.37).    atRegressiontest.GuruLogin.test(GuruLogin.java.62).      so HomePage.java.37 is the line 37 in my HomePage Class which is element.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/input[1]")); in above code.              I am using PageObject Model without page factory.

Comment: You have typo there Pageobjects.HomePage.UerName(HomePage.java.37).
Should be UserName not UerName

Answer (score 0):

By changing the scope in pom.xml from test to compile . It's Worked for me